# How can I create a binary column based on the values of several other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which contains 7 binary columns (True, False). I want to create a new column binary column that flags 1 if all of the others flag 1, and 0 if any of the others flag 0.

I have tried:

```
df["new_col"] = np.where(df[["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7"]]>0,1,0)
```

but I get this error:

> Wrong number of items passed 7, placement implies 1

I know what this means, but I don't know which tool to use to get this operation done.

How could I do this?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if all values per rows (axis=1) are `True` and then cast to integer for `True/False` to `1/0` map:

```
cols = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7"]
df["new_col"] = df[cols].all(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Alternative with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df["new_col"] = np.where(df[cols].all(axis=1), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @jezrael!! This is exactly what i was looking for:D